# Skipping row when importing csv with php

Tags: php, csv

I tried to read data from a csv file into a php and it worked beautifully with this:

```
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$f = fopen("0001.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($line as $cell) {
            echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
```

Is it possible to skip the first two lines of the csv file, or better still, keep them separate from the table data which starts on line three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can skip them by using a simple counter

```
$count = 0;
```

Then in your for loop

```
foreach ($line as $cell) {
    if ($count < 2) {
        $count++;
        continue;
    }
    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
}
```

This will skip the first two lines, if you want to keep them separate you can append them to another variable or put them in an array

Comment: Thank you. If I change if ($count < 2) { to if ($count > 2) { would that only display the very first two rows of the csv?

Comment: yes, but in this case better continue replace with break